# How to merge two lines in the exact place as if it is pulled up/down using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

A sample output of my file is given here

```
! S R Number  :            Class :       ! 
                635035               3     
! Name        :                          ! 
                ADAM BASHA               
+========================================+ 
! Code  ! Description     !       Amount ! 
+========================================+ 
! 2222  ! Tech.Exam Allow !       340.00 ! 
! 3104  ! D A             !    19,524.43 ! 
! 3107  ! H R A           !     3,984.40 ! 
! 4113  ! Transport Allow !       460.00 ! 
!                         :              ! 
  Net Amount Payable  :        24,308.83
! S R Number  :            Class :       ! 
                551820               2     
! Name        :                          ! 
                TOM SMITH              
+========================================+ 
! Code  ! Description     !       Amount ! 
+========================================+ 
! 3104  ! D A             !    19,404.41 ! 
! 3107  ! H R A           !     3,960.60 ! 
! 4113  ! Transport Allow !       460.00 ! 
!                         :              ! 
  Net Amount Payable  :        23,825.01   
! S R Number  :            Class :       ! 
                550044               3     
! Name        :                          ! 
                ROBERT LOUIS
```

I want every two lines similar to this format given below to be merged

```
 ! S R Number  :            Class :       ! 
                635035               3
```

I want the two lines to be merged as follows

```
! S R Number  : 635035     Class :   3   !
```

And the entire result should be as follows :

```
! S R Number  : 635035     Class :   3   ! 
! Name        : ADAM BASHA               ! 
+========================================+ 
! Code  ! Description     !       Amount ! 
+========================================+ 
! 2222  ! Tech.Exam Allow !       340.00 ! 
! 3104  ! D A             !    19,524.43 ! 
! 3107  ! H R A           !     3,984.40 ! 
! 4113  ! Transport Allow !       460.00 ! 
! Net Amount Payable  :        24,308.83 !
! S R Number  : 551820     Class :   2   ! 
! Name        : TOM SMITH                !
+========================================+ 
! Code  ! Description     !       Amount ! 
+========================================+ 
! 3104  ! D A             !    19,404.41 ! 
! 3107  ! H R A           !     3,960.60 ! 
! 4113  ! Transport Allow !       460.00 ! 
! Net Amount Payable  :        23,825.01 !
! S R Number  : 550044     Class :   3   ! 
! Name        : ROBERT LOUIS             !
```

The file is too big, so I have posted a sample of it.  This output file seems to be splitting some lines into two lines, like the lines containing `S R Number, Name and Net Amount Payable`. Please provide a solution to this.

The answers already given work fine, only thing is they process all the lines instead of only the lines which are split.  Thanks to all.

I have edited my question using a practical example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[^[:space:]]/ {
    if (NR>1) { print buf }
    buf = $0
    next
}
{
    if (/:/) { sub(/:/," ",buf) }
    while ( match($0,/[^[:space:]]+/) ) {
        buf = substr(buf,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) substr(buf,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        $0 = sprintf("%*s",RSTART+RLENGTH-1,"") substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
END { print buf }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
! S R Number  : 635035     Class :   3   !
! Name        : ADAM BASHA               !
+========================================+
! Code  ! Description     !       Amount !
+========================================+
! 2222  ! Tech.Exam Allow !       340.00 !
! 3104  ! D A             !    19,524.43 !
! 3107  ! H R A           !     3,984.40 !
! 4113  ! Transport Allow !       460.00 !
! Net Amount Payable  :        24,308.83 !
! S R Number  : 551820     Class :   2   !
! Name        : TOM SMITH                !
+========================================+
! Code  ! Description     !       Amount !
+========================================+
! 3104  ! D A             !    19,404.41 !
! 3107  ! H R A           !     3,960.60 !
! 4113  ! Transport Allow !       460.00 !
! Net Amount Payable  :        23,825.01 !
! S R Number  : 550044     Class :   3   !
! Name        : ROBERT LOUIS             !
```

Comment: It's more of what **shouldn't** you do :-). awk is for manipulating text. period. full stop. If you want to do anything other than that (moving files around? killing processes?) you should use something else (e.g. shell).

Comment: All the solutions provided are working great, but it is processing for all the lines in the file.  I only need to merge the two lines - one having **Name** and the other having the **actual name**, as in the question.  I have many such occurrences in the file.  I need to merge the two lines having those two patterns as above.  Thank you all for excellent solutions.

Comment: @EdMorton, I have edited my question and provided more truly representative sample input/output with clarity in my requirements.

Comment: **Excellent** solution sir.  Thank you very much @EdMorton

Answer (score 1):

another `gawk` solution using one-char length fields

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=""} 
            {if(NR%2) split($0,p);
             else {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==" ") $i=p[i]; 
                   print}}' file

Name : Adam Basha                     Class :3
```

here assumes second record is longer than first record (if not change loop end condition to max of length(p) and NF or append the extras afterwards.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind you indention?

Comment: better?  The intention of indentation is `condition{action}` blocks aligned at action, same level statements at same level indentation.  If it flows in the line and short (like `if(x) y` keep on the same line.  I don't have a pretty printer and sometimes make mistakes...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TSb9kitU I hope that helps. And btw, I don't have a pretty printer as well. I'm the pretty printer ;)

Comment: Too many curly braces for my taste, `awk --profile` will give you better looking code if you want, however I like denser, one-liner style.

Comment: No, no, no. It's not about like it or not. It's about rock solid, readable and maintainable code. While I agree that for a one line idiom the rules are a bit different, the above code is obviously not a one line idiom and *your* style of indention makes it hard to read, hard to get and hard to maintain. The fact that you never place inline comments might be another result of your "style" of indention.

Answer (score 0):

This (not very elegant) command should do the job for an input-file `test`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{odd=1}
     odd{line=$0;odd=0;next}
     {odd=1;nline=""
      for(i=1; i<=length($0);i++){
          nline=substr($0,i,1)==" " && i <= length(line)? nline""substr(line,i,1) : nline""substr($0,i,1)
      }
     print nline
     }' test
```

Output:

```
Name : Adam Basha                     Class : 3
```

Comment: `odd` can be written as `NR%2`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;/\n\s/!{P;D};s/^/\n/;ta;:a;/\n.*\n$/s/\n//g;t;s/\n\n/\n \n/;s/\n(\S)(.*)\n./\1\n\2\n/;ta;s/\n.(.*)\n(.)/\2\n\1\n/;ta' file
```

The process combines the required lines and using unique markers (newlines) moving left to right, compare the single characters following a marker. If the first is not a space keep it and advance the markers over it. Otherwise, replace the first by the second and advance the markers over it. If the markers has reached the end of line remove the markers excepting when the first line is shorter than the second when an additional space is introduced on the first line.